# A specific Request is not getting recording in Jmeter 2.9

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, chunked-encoding, chunked, http-chunked

I tried to record a complete screen but unable to record a single Response.

The Screen is for getting live data. So when I clicked on Live Data the page is getting recorded(Jmeter2.9) apart from the Response which contains the Live Data.

It is saying that "Sorry the Connection is Offline"(I tried the same scenario with browser it is perfectly working.

It is only with Jmeter)

While Loading the page I am getting the **Jmeter Log:**

```
2014/06/18 21:43:31 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: Problem with SSL certificate? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.HttpRequestHdr.parse(HttpRequestHdr.java:110)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:197)
```

****But I am able to Record all other https request/response in the same Server and screen but it has issue with only one Request. I also tried to import the Certificate.

**Response Header:**

```
Cache-Control   private
Connection  keep-alive
Date    Wed, 18 Jun 2014 16:30:13 GMT
Expires Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
access-control-allow-orig...    *
```

**Request Header:**

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  JSESSIONID= [hidden]; uid=-9223372036794645800; clid=-9223372036794645800; sid=-9223372036794645800; cd=2014-06-19
Host    [hidden]
Referer [hidden]
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
```

***Is it because of Transfer-Encoding   chunked ???

Please help me I am stuck with this since last 2 days.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try following [Recording HTTPS Traffic with JMeter's Proxy Server](http://blazemeter.com/blog/recording-https-traffic-jmeters-proxy-server) guide steps.

Perhaps starting with clean session should resolve your issue.

Alternatively you can try recording your use case via [JMeter Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-load-testi/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en)